# What is the best way to perform UI work within an overriden dialog method and finish by calling it's super

Tags: java, android

What is the best way to architect code to achieve the following...

- Caller instantiates a custom Dialog class
- Caller calls overriden Dialog.show() method
- Within Dialog.show() i'd like to
- --- Execute some code that runs on the UI thread
- --- Wait for that code to complete
- --- Finish the call to Dialog.show() by calling it's super.show()

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to overwrite dialog.show().
Do something along the lines of:

- Create your custom dialog class
- call doThenShow()

  ```
  public void doThenShow(){    
      m_taskactivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
          //Do some ui stuff
          //dialog.show()
      }
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion Chris, but after calling show(), .isShowing() always returns false.  If I call show() outside of the runnable .isShowing() works again.

Comment: Update.  Moving Runnable code outside of the custom Dialog class works.  So the BIG question, why would .isShowing always return false if I call .show() from within a Runnable within the class itself, but properly return true/false if I call dialogInstance.show within the same runnable outside of the class?  Am I missing something obvious here?